# Fetching shell windows throws access denied exception HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) from non-admin user

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, internet-explorer, windows

I am trying to automate Internet Explorer.
To get handle of running Internet Explorer on the system I am using this statement

```
 Dim allWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
```

It works fine from an admin user on the system. But running the same code piece from a non-admin user throws this exception.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

So I want to know what kind of privileges required to fetch the ShellWindows?
Or if there is some alternate way to fetch ShellWindows without any privilege restriction?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because UAC permission. One should have admin rights to fetch the ShellWindows.
You can enable UAC in your code as:
Add app.manifest file in your project.
Modify the  requestedExecutionLevel tag as below:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: I don't require admin rights for my application. At first sight I thought the problem is due to the non-admin user but it's not, it's due to the Run As user.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem myself. Actually it's not due to the admin or non-admin user. When we logged in into the system from any user it works fine but the case when it won't run is

> Logged in as some user and run the application from another user using
>   Run As option in windows

Then windows will not allows you to fetch the ShellWindows and this behaviour seems fine due to security reasons.